# how to write simple component test in python using behave

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i am trying to learn how to write component test using behave in python
if you can share few video links or articles that will be help full.

to start with simple example adding 2 numbers and finding the sum of it ? how do we write component test for these.

Answer (score -1):

[the doc](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has examples and tutorials:

```
from behave import *

@given('we have behave installed')
def step_impl(context):
    pass

@when('we implement a test')
def step_impl(context):
    assert True is not False

@then('behave will test it for us!')
def step_impl(context):
    assert context.failed is False
```

[This website](https://www.google.com/search?q=behave+tutorial) has a list of video tutorials for behave.

Comment: Downvote all you want, reading the doc should be the first thing to do **before** asking a question like that. And yes, this is an answer to the question that is posted as an answer to the question.

Comment: i didn't downvote just to clarify that, i told that because there were link only in your answer. now its not. so this is kind of an answer

Comment: He's basically asking for links.

Comment: but link only answer will be deleted by the reviewers, regardless of what's in the question.